# Mapping is not working when run spring boot application standalone

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used spring boot in my project. when I start the application using ide everything is okay, but when I run the jar file and open the first page in browser, I see this text :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/login.html
```

Spring boot configuration class is :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableCaching
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@Import({SecurityLauncher.class})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class Launcher extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Launcher.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Edit -> Project tree

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── app
│   │       │   ├── css
│   │       │   ├── js
│   │       │   │   ├── controllers
│   │       │   │   ├── directives
│   │       │   │   ├── factory
│   │       │   │   ├── filters
│   │       │   │   └── services
│   │       │   ├── lib
│   │       │   ├── resources
│   │       │   ├── templates
│   │       │   └── view
│   │       └── WEB-INF
|   |       |__ index and login files
│   └── test
│       └── java
```

Edit 2 -> Spring security config:

```
public class SecurityLauncher extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/*", "/login.html*").permitAll().antMatchers("/*").authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").loginPage("/login.html")
                .passwordParameter("password").usernameParameter("username").defaultSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserSecurityProvider securityProvider) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(securityProvider);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the file login.html stored?

Comment: @dunni in webapp folder

Comment: Please add the project file tree, so we can undertand what's happening

Comment: @reos I've added the project tree to the question

Comment: Your index.html files is a JSP ?

Comment: i had a similar problem and i resolved putting @ComponentScan(basePackages = "path.to.controller")
in class that corespond to your Launcher.class

Comment: @Cassian I have put it on my Launcher class, But I did not added it to this question. I said that in my ide everything is okay

Comment: @reos it is  a simple html file

Comment: do you have @SpringBootApplication to in Launcher ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, in a Spring Boot application you place your static files under `src/main/resources/static`, `src/main/resources/public`, `src/main/resources/resources` or `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources`. Your templates belong to `src/main/resources/templates`.

The official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) says:

> Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.

Comment: I did it, but problem exists. Should I add a config to read resource from the public or static directories?

Comment: Remove overridden methods `addResourceHandlers`,  `dispatcherServlet` and `configureDefaultServletHandling` from your Launcher class.

Comment: Reduce your launcher to a bare minimum in order to isolate the root cause. Remove all annotations and add `@SpringBootApplication`. Exclude all autoconfigured beans and remove all deps expect `spring-boot-starter-web`. Basically, start from scratch with [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/) and use just the `Web` dependency. Copy your assets into the new project and check whether you can access it through a running standalone application.

Comment: I've moved project to the empty project that created by Spring Initializr and it my problem solved. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. Now you can do a binary search and narrow down your problem:-)

Answer (score 2):

The @SpringBootApplication is scanning for controller in the wrong package and does not find the controller so you have to remove @SpringBootApplication and let @ComponentScan(basePackages = "...") look for controller to get scaned right. Do you see a mapping message in log when you start for login.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a html file you need to add to the path ***src/main/resources/static***

```
src/main/resources/static/index.html
```

And the call it

```
http://{IP}:{port}/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in contextPath.
there are two ways to solve it:

1. run your app without any contextPath. eg http://localhost:8080/hello
2. or set your contextPath in application.properties as server.contextPath=/myapp
   and then access the url as: http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriding the addResourceHandlers method.

In a stand-alone web application the default servlet from the container is also enabled, and acts as a fallback, serving content from the root of the ServletContext if Spring decides not to handle it. Most of the time this will not happen (unless you modify the default MVC configuration) because Spring will always be able to handle requests through the DispatcherServlet.

By default, resources are mapped on /** but you can tune that via spring.mvc.static-path-pattern. For instance, relocating all resources to /resources/** can be achieved as follows:

spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**

Hope helpful!!!